# How can I start a task that keeps running

Tags: ansible

Suppose I have a WildFly server that I remote install onto a machine with Ansible. Now I want Ansible to start it by running the `standalone.sh` script.

```
- name: start wildfly
      shell: "{{bin}}/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 2>&1 >/dev/null "
      args:
        chdir: "/tmp/{{wildfly}}"
```

When I do that, the server gets started, but my Ansible playbook hangs.
When I add `&` at the end of the command line (which is why I use the shell task), the server starts and is immediately killed.
(Similar when I use `command` instead of `shell`.

I understand that the `service` task requires an entry in `/etc/init.d` or similar, so that is not really of help.

Comment: You can try with `nohup ....your_command... &`

Comment: Why aren't you making a service?

Comment: That would require modifying /etc/init.d which is not really desirable at the moment. But perhaps that is the only way.

Comment: Unless you absolutely have to, don't reinvent the wheel, quickly googling showed me at least 2 roles that handle install and config of wildfly server, including setting up a service. If it suits your needs, use those existing roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that the service task requires an entry in `/etc/init.d` or similar, so that is not really of help.

Create one. An Upstart service can be as easy as a couple simple lines. [Here's an example for Papertrail's `remote_syslog`](https://gist.github.com/ceejayoz/bd9ccbc59115a53e6741).